# "Да, я ответить на вопрос"

Tags: дефект, обсуждение, статус-завершено, локализация

Можно так:

- Да, ответить на вопрос
- Да, ответить на собственный вопрос

> [image: http://c2n.me/3gmwNyR.png]

Comment: Может, это для тех, кто не ошень хорошо разговаривать на руски язык?

Comment: @VladD, возможно аудитория часть большая всё же говорить на очень хорошо руски язык.

Comment: Я добавить нужная метки на вопрос.

Comment: А я комментировать вопрос.

Answer (score 6):

Изменил в Транзифексе на "Да, я хочу ответить" (оригинал: Yes, I want to post an answer).